# .toBeInstanceOf(String) on buffer.toString() in Jest tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

How can I use `expect(str).toBeInstanceOf(String)` in a Jest assertion for a string that has been created using `Buffer#toString()`?

Or is the correct thing to do here `expect(typeof str).toEqual('string')` instead?

---

#### Details:

This test case, using `typeof`, passes:

```
it('should test a Buffer.toString() - typeof', () => {
  const buf = new Buffer('hello world');
  const str = buf.toString('hex');
  expect(buf).toBeInstanceOf(Buffer);
  expect(typeof str).toEqual('string');
  // expect(str).toBeInstanceOf(String);
});
```

However, this test case, using `.toBeInstanceOf()`, fails:

```
it('should test a Buffer.toString()', () => {
  const buf = new Buffer('hello world');
  const str = buf.toString('hex');
  expect(buf).toBeInstanceOf(Buffer);
  // expect(typeof str).toEqual('string');
  expect(str).toBeInstanceOf(String);
});
```

Here's the Jest output for it:

```
 FAIL  ./buffer.jest.js
  ● should test a Buffer.toString()

    expect(value).toBeInstanceOf(constructor)

    Expected value to be an instance of:
      "String"
    Received:
      "68656c6c6f20776f726c64"
    Constructor:
      "String"

      at Object.<anonymous>.it (password.jest.js:11:15)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have a look at the [toBeInstanceOf implementation](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/e84f1544a8fea05f21424f00ee6e53fa666dbbe7/packages/expect/src/matchers.js#L165), you'll see that `instanceof` is used for checking, but as you can see it demonstrated in [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), `string primitive` is not the same thing as `String` derived from `Object`.

Your first variant is the correct way to check:

```js
expect(typeof str).toEqual('string');
```